# Is there a table object with sorting functionality freely available for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

I am in need of an abstraction for tables in a JavaScript application that is heavily table-based. I plan on making a JavaScript class with the following functions

- Constructor to create the table from an array of objects
- Constructor to create the table from an array of headers and an array of data
- Methods for sorting by any of the columns
- Methods for splitting the table into pages and traversing them
- Methods for tying the object to a HTML element, drawing a HTML table representation inside it

The class will be small, light and contained in a single JavaScript file. Also the class will be free to use for anybody.

But before I possibly reinvent the wheel, I have to ask:

**Does something like this exist already?** *(I couldn't find anything)*

Comment: ExtJS has something similar called Grids.  Free for non-commericial and/or open-source use.  It's slightly more configuration than what you have listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The class will be small, light and contained in a single JavaScript file. Also the class will be free to use for anybody.

Once you have that restriction, I'm pretty sure that the tradeoff between using someone's API or implementing your own will lead you to 'reinvent the wheel', because the time to understand that API and adapt it to your current code maybe is not worth, compared to the effort to implement.

Anyway, if you still wants to use some API, i've found [this](http://www.ultimatesmashing.com/coding/tables-javascript-framworks-libraries/) post somewhere that maybe can help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want write one more sortable table class? There are some good one already.

Look at jqGrid for example. It is free open source. You can download it [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6), see different demos [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Additionally you can find the latest source code of jqGrid on [GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid).

Comment: What part of jqGrid is light? First of all it's split up into tens of files, and the main file is 112kb.

Comment: @Codemonkey: If you want to read the code it would be enough for your purpose to examine the code of `grid.base.js`. The code of `grid.common.js` and even more `jquery.fmatter.js` can gives additional information. The local sorting and filtering of data are starting with [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.0/js/grid.base.js#L150). If you have interest for local data only see always the case `datatype:'local'` (`.p.datatype`). The local data are saved in `.p.data` array and and `.p._index` map.